# Identity 2 RoleStore Error

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, structuremap, asp.net-identity, asp.net-web-api2

In my WebApi 2 app I am using StructureMap. The error is being thrown in my ConfigureContainer.

The error: There is no implicit reference conversion from Microsoft.Asp.Identity.EntityFramework.RoleStore to Microsoft.Asp.Identity.EntityFramework.IRoleStore

The IUserStore code is exactly the same and no error thrown there.

```
public void ConfigureContainer()
    {
        ObjectFactory.Configure(x =>
            {
                x.For<DbContext>().Use(() => new ApartmentContext());
                x.For<IAuthRepository>().Use<AuthRepository>();
                x.For<IUserStore<ApplicationUser>>().Use<UserStore<ApplicationUser>>();
                x.For<IRoleStore<ApplicationRole>>().Use<RoleStore<ApplicationRole>>(); <-- error thrown here
            });
    }
```

Comment: If you look closely at the following post where the OP answered his own question (but within an edit of the original question): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22779618/structuremap-web-api-2-and-iuserrolestore-error -- he is claiming that making a slight syntax change will correct the problem.  The change is easy -- give it a try.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I followed that post and its compiling now, time to test..